# WordPress admin-ajax.php 404

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Okay, I've been struggling with this for hours now.

When I try to customize my theme, it gives me `admin-ajax.php` 404 on both POST and GET requests, and does not allow me to make the desired changes :/
The file is definitely there, triple checked via cPanel.

[image]

Ran fresh install of WordPress three times now, both the newest 4.4.2 and older down to 4.2.0 because, who knows.

This happens in the default themes and any theme I add. So confused. Help?

Comment: did you checked admin-ajax.php have a enough permission?

Comment: Not quite sure where I go about this?

Comment: Mh, you know what, did try to change some permissions on it earlier in the file manager. Is that what you're referring too? Gave User execute permission as well. Didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Can you show your `.htaccess` contents?